# Merge xz files in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

I just downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I have 2 files with xz extension: in.tsv.xz and expected.tsv.xz - each of them consists of one column and the same number of rows.
I want to merge them into one file with 2 columns.

If I first unpack one of them (let say expected.tsv.xz) I can achieve it by:

```
xzcat in.tsv.xz | paste expected.tsv -
```

How can I achieve it without unpacking?

Comment: (Incidentally be said that Ubuntu 20.04 was launched today) the xzcat is decompressing to the stout and the - option is merging the column from the expected.tsv with the stin ( that comes from the other site of the pipe where it is a stout). all you have to do now is to pipe the stout from the paste thru another pipe and compress it with xz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I achieve it without unpacking?

You can't. The files are compressed; to do anything with their contents you have to decompress them. Something like

```
paste <(xzcat in.tsv.xz) <(xzcat expected.tsv.xz) | xz > combined.tsv.xz
```

will do it all in one single pipeline.